# Как подключить smartGWT к GWT проекту с помощью Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, maven, smartgwt

Всем привет, сколько бочку не делал пока не могу понять, как подключить smartGWT к уже существующему GWT проекту. IDE - Intellij, на сайте smartGWT нашел 2 зависимости:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.eval</groupId>
   <artifactId>isomorphic-core-rpc</artifactId>
   <version>6.0-p20160514</version>
</dependency>
```

и

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.eval</groupId>
   <artifactId>isc-batchuploader</artifactId>
   <version>6.0-p20160514</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

но maven подсвечивает их красным и не импортирует. Направьте меня пожалуйста на путь истинный, как мне добавить этот фреймворк?
З.ы. я скачал их (smartGWT) trial версию на 60 дней. Архив весит не много, ни мало 350 метров и в нем куча всего кроме библиотек, пока не могу понять для чего все, то, что там есть.

Answer (score 1):

Ищите здесь: http://mvnrepository.com/

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.smartgwt/smartgwt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Для smartgwt LGPL этого вроде как достаточно, но проблема в том что я хоту подключить EE edition ну или pro+ на худой конец. Мне нужен smartgwt server

Comment: Ничего не могу вам про это сказать, не имел с ним дел